# Is there a way that to add models, data access classes, web api controllers after an ASP.Net web application is compiled and deployed?

Tags: asp.net

I am building an on-premise ASP.Net application, and want other parties to be able to extend what I have built without needing to recompile the application.  Is there a way that you can add models, data access layers and web api controllers after the web application is compiled and deployed?

Thus far, I have developed a solution where I can manage the actual pages via a special web form and store the page template/css/script in the database.

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to create a Content Management System (CMS). It's not a trivial thing to do. It's not something that would fit in the scope of a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I'm not asking how to build the entire application, just inquiring as to whether or not you can add classes to an already compiled asp.net application.

Comment: Sure. You can do that.